# Is there a verb form of the word "Suppository"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've heard people slangily refer to "suppositing" something as a verb for what a person would do with a suppository.  I don't see any references citing "supposit" as a verb.  Is there a verb form of this word?

If not, what are some other good words for that action that sound less crass than an explicit description of it?

Comment: You should include whatever research you did... [the dictionaries I looked at](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supposit) do not support this idea; maybe you could re-purpose it.

Comment: [... _insert_  suppository](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supposit)

Comment: Backpacking? ....

Comment: Physicians just let you figure it out. [Eddie Murphy would rather play golf than this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07P538K83iU)

Comment: BTW...I was just wondering who you are hanging out with that the topic of "suppositing" should come up so often, unless you are an RN or doctor. It might help.

Comment: Suppose there is ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppositorize

> As long as money, fame and love are to be won, professional athletes will continue to swallow, snort, shoot up, huff and "suppositorize" strange chemicals.

(Hartsfield, *[Huffing Xenon a New Cheat for Athletes](https://www.realclearscience.com/blog/2014/09/huffing_noble_gases_a_new_cheat_for_athletes.html)*, RealClearScience)

> 2.00pm
>   Jim slung out while they suppositorise, catheterise and cross-stitch his wife. Goes for a sandwich.

(Jim Cromwell, *[Birth](https://www.jimcromwell.com/stuff/2001/12/birth.html)*, on "Holly and Rosie's Stuff".)

Answer (score 0):

A "[suppository](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/suppository?s=t)" is a medicinal capsule generally inserted into one's anus, though for women, it can also refer to inserting it into the vagina.

Therefore, in slang, the transitive verb "[supposit](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=suppository)" is a round about way, or maybe euphemistic way, of saying "[shove *it* up your ass](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stick--it?s=t)" (see def. 8).  This is a vulgar expression one says in contempt, albeit sometimes sarcastic contempt, and can be specific to a real item that is being referred to as "it" or in replacement of "it" but very often simply uses "it" intangibly to loosely refer to everything the person it's being said to just said, their opinion, or even the entire disagreement or situation.

Examples:

- "Thanks for your input, but why don't you supposit it?"
- "You want your money?  Well, here's your money.  Now go and supposit it!"
- "Oh, so I'm not good enough for you?  Supposit it!"

Comment: Suppose it isn't it, then?

Comment: Hello Billy...I am having trouble locating _"the transitive verb "supposit"_ at the link you have to the word. Can you please provide us with the citation from the source?

Comment: Although Billy might have been coming from the dark side, that should make perfect sense to anyone whose language uses suppository… Consider https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supposit